# Consuming the web service which you created using Android application and Dot Net

Tags: android

I need consuming the web service which you created using Android application and Dot Net.

My problem is in the output of the page because in this page not possible scrolled and I can't view all the information recorded in my page.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Here is my code:

```
public class WebServiceDemoActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://.../WebService/GetCustomers";
    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "GetCustomers";
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://.../WebService";
    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://.../WebService.asmx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(textView);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                OPERATION_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try {

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
             textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(response.toString()));

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            textView.setText(exception.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
setContentView(textView);
```

to this:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);       
TextView textView = new TextView(this); 
sv.addView(textView);
setContentView(sv);
```